# MS Visio Standard customizing Outgoing and Incoming Off Page References

Tags: colors, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010, shapes, standards

I am trying to make a stencil for my job and so far I have done a pretty good job I think.

However, I am having **trouble** in one area regarding an “***off page reference***”. Now, I was able to do a ***hyperlink reference***, where if you drag the shape to the document, then it’ll have a *drop-down menu* that you choose from with whatever number image you’re trying to associate with, and it will drop the shape on the desired page, and then change the number within the shape accordingly…that was difficult for me to do, but I did it. I feel like what I’m wanting to do is similar to that but I’m having a brain fart.

Now, regarding the “***outgoing off page reference***” with the ***incoming*** and ***outgoing*** option, I have the outgoing shape and color one way, and the “***incoming off page reference***” as another shape and another color, however, when I place the outgoing off page reference shape on the document and select the page it will be dropped on, when I select ***incoming*** for the newly dropped shape it only changes the ***shape*** and not the ***color*** of the shape.